Discrimination in divorce proceedings
I am a Russian born opera singer, married in Russia, with my husband who is an American opera singer. I have American citizenship. We have two sons, American citizens, 17 years old and 10 years old. My husband and I have careers. We travelled many years all over the world where, most of the time, my sons were with me!
To be together more often as a family, he moved us to Berlin because we had an Apartment here. After Corona, two years of not working, the Russian-Ukrainian war (which affected my career), he started a divorce process in Germany to not pay alimony and child support as an American citizen. Behind my back, he applied for a divorce in Berlin, leaving me without money to hire a lawyer to protect my rights as an American citizen.
I am trying to find representation of my women's rights, abandonment of my husband of 18 years, total neglect and emotional distress. Because I cannot fight such a difficult international case in a foreign country with the language barrier, or without lawyers and the support of family and friends in America .
I’m depressed, emotionally exhausted, have no work or income, and am completely dependent on my husband‘s mercy. He has total control of my life and my kids and forbids us to go to the US. I am seeking psychological help during the divorce and looking for legal advice on how to dismiss my case.

If you have US citizenship I can’t see how your husband can forbid you to go to the US. Your situation sounds very difficult, it might help you get an answer if you edit your question to include what routes to legal advice you’ve tried so far, and the outcome.

I don't think dismissing a divorce case is possible, and filing for divorce where you're resident is not unreasonable. You need to find an attorney to help you (and may be a coach/counselor to help with coping). This is going to be difficult, both emotionally and financially, but there are rules in place to help you through this and prevent abusive behaviors. You just need to find the right attorney to work with.

Sympathize as we do, there doesn't seem to be a question here that we can answer. Talk to a lawyer.

@littleadv it should be possible to get a divorce case dismissed if it has been filed in an inappropriate jurisdiction (and perhaps for other procedural reasons).  However, as you note, most jurisdictions will divorce couples who reside in the jurisdiction.  OP really needs a German divorce lawyer to understand whether it might be possible in this case and, if not, how to protect her interests through the German system.

It's also unlikely that a German court would sanction a divorce settlement significantly worse for you than another jurisdiction.

"he started a divorce process in Germany to not pay alimony and child support as an American citizen" Germany, nor any other nation, will have no say in whether he will have to pay child support to meet with obligations emplaced upon him in the United States.

Since you are living in Berlin, that is the appropriate place to file for divorce. You won't be able to stop your husband from divorcing you. What you should seek instead is:

A fair share of your joint property.
If you current have no income, but your husband has, you can expect alimny for some time until you can reasonably be expected to earn your own money again.
Custody of your children (assuming you want that).
Child support for your children, as long as they are underaged and living with you (he'll still have to pay child support after they turn 18, but then probably to them, not to you).

Based on my rough impressions of US and German law, you probably have better rights as a German resident here than you have as a US citizen. Protecting the weaker party is a strong feature of German family law.
It is generally reasonable to expect that a German lawyer can speak English, althogh not everyone will be comfortable relying on it when speaking with clients. However, in Berlin it will be easy enough to find a family lawyer who is used to representing foreigners. In fact, it was easy enough for me to find a Russian speaking family lawyer in Berlin using Google. You'll pay the lawyer once the divorce is done, and then you'll have money.
